# Quote of Seneca

Tags: meaning, quotations

> “Behold a worthy sight, to which God, turning his attention to his own
>   work, may direct his gaze. Behold an equal thing, worthy of a God, a
>   brave man matched in conflict with evil fortune”
>
> Seneca

I find his quote so confusing. Could you explain or paraphrase it to me!?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> “Behold a worthy sight, to which God, turning his attention to his own
>   work, may direct his gaze. Behold an equal thing, worthy of a God, a
>   brave man matched in conflict with evil fortune”

**Behold** is a command, an imperative.  It means "Look upon" but you can understand it here to mean "Consider" or "Look upon  and think about".

Here is a noun phrase:

> ... a worthy sight to which God may direct his gaze.

A worthy sight God may look at.  When may God look at this worthy sight?  When *turning his attention to his own work*. When contemplating creation as a whole, or something created, or an individual creature, or a species, like humankind.

So, God is imagined as gazing at something or someone or some species which God has created, at some piece of Creation.

Here is another noun-phrase:

> ... a brave man matched in conflict with evil fortune

That man is "an equal thing, worthy of a God" -- that is, equal to the first "worthy sight", whatever God was imagined to be looking at. And that man is a worthy creation of a God.

A brave man matched in conflict with evil fortune is just as worthy  a creation as anything and everything else that God has created. That man matched in conflict with evil fortune is a fitting thing even for the Creator to behold.

P.S. The second translation OP offers:

> "Behold a sight worthy to be viewed by a god interested in his own
>   work, behold a pair worthy of a god, a brave man matched with evil
>   fortune"

yields some light and affects how the two sentences may be understood in relation to each other. Above I had understood **an equal thing** to be comparing the sight of a man struggling against evil fortune  with some *other* piece of Creation God was gazing at, but the passage could be referring to that contest in both sentences. The **equal thing** would be the *evenly matched pair* of man and evil fortune rather than a comparison with the earlier "worthy sight".

Comment: And, again, consider has some meaning too. Does it mean "care about"?
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consider

Comment: That man matched in conflict with evil fortune deserves to be called Godlike or having excellence worthy of God?

Comment: I still don't understand the use of "worthy of a God" there. Is it the same as the example : "He threw a party worthy of a millionaire."
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worthy

Comment: Why did he write "a God", instead of "God"?

Comment: Seneca was a Roman. This is a translation from the Latin.

Comment: "worthy of" does not mean "like"; rather it can be paraphrased as "befitting".  So "worthy of a God" is not be understood as "deserves to be called godlike" but as "befitting a God".

Comment: Thanks. I found another translation of this quote:
"Behold a sight worthy to be viewed by a god interested in his own work, behold a pair worthy of a god, a brave man matched with evil fortune"
Do the two translations have the same meaning?

Comment: *Approximately* the same meaning in some respects but differ markedly in others, e.g., the one has **behold an equal thing** and the  other **behold a pair**. I took **an equal thing** to be anaphoric, referring back to that piece of Creation God was contemplating in the first clause; but it can be taken as a cataphoric reference, describing the equally matched pair, man and evil fortune. But I see nothing in the second translation to make me think that "worthy of a god" could mean "deserves to be called Godlike", since if that were the case, "evil fortune" would deserve to be called godlike.

Comment: In other words, both clauses could be referring to the same thing. I will add a P.S.